# Python/Pandas: Conditional summing of columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

In python I have a pandas data frame similar to the one below:

```
           | AUG12               | UNDERLYING | VOL |
           |---------------------|            |     |
           | 45  | 49  | 50 | 55 |            |     |
====================================================|
2012-11-14 | 1   | 1   | 2  | 3  | 49         | ?   |
...          ...   ...   ...   ...
```

The task is: For each row, find column names which are greater than `UNDERLYING` (49), sum the values (2+3) and put the result in to `VOL` (5). How can I accomplish this in python? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use DataFrame.apply function

```
def conditional_sum(row):
    underlying = row['UNDERLYING'][0]  # extra '[0]' is required due to multi leve index in column names
    return row.loc['AUG12'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x < underlying else x).sum()

df.apply(conditional_sum, axis=1)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I had to replace `AUG12` with the range of my columns. But your snippet did the trick!